# Finding a steady-state solution to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, steady-state

> **Problem I'm Facing:** If it exists, find the steady-state temperature solution for the PDE
>   $$u_t = u_{xx} + 1$$
>   with the boundary conditions
>   $$u_x (0,t) = 1 \;\;\;\;\; u(L,t) = 1-L$$

This has come up in a homework assignment in my class on PDEs. However, the professor isn't teaching much of the underlying theory or methods and is making the lectures *extremely* hard to follow, so this is ultimately feeling more like a self-study than anything, so I'm not feeling very confident.

So I have tried to attempt the above problem. As given in our text, a steady-state solution is one that will not vary with time. Let $U(x)$ be such a solution: then, per the text, we must have

$$kU''(x) = 0 \implies U(x) = c_1 x + c_2$$

for constants $k,c_1,c_2$, and of course the time derivative is zero.

In that light, letting $u(x,t) = U(x)$ and using the above, we seem to get

$$u_t = u_{xx} + 1 \implies 0 = 0 + 1 \implies 0 = 1$$

*Obviously* this is not true, so this seems to imply no such steady state solution exists.

But my lack of confidence makes me feel like that this is just way too easy and that I'm completely going the wrong way with this. Is this at all right? How exactly would I find the solution?

Comment: If it doesn't vary with time, then the time derivative $u_t$ is zero. That means you'll end up with an ordinary differential equation to solve, and then you just check that you can satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: For the steady state solution, $u_t =0$, so your new equation is going to be something like $u''(x) = -1$. The BC are $u'(0) =1$ and $u(L) = 1 -L$. Try it now..

Comment: So if the time derivative is $0$, and $U(x)$ our steady-state solution, then we get

$$0 = U''(x) + 1$$

where $U(x) = c_1 x + c_2$. The boundary conditions become

$$U'(x) = c_1 \implies U'(0) = 1 \implies c_1 = 1$$

and 

$$U(x) = c_1 x + c_2 \implies U(L) = 1 - L = L + c_2 \implies c_2 = 1 - 2L$$

Thus, 

$$U(x) = x + (1 - 2L)$$

would satisfy the boundary conditions, and thus be our solution? Is that what you mean @dbx ?

Comment: The general solution should be quadratic, i.e. $U(x) = c_1x +c_2 -\frac{x^2}{2}$

Comment: Okay, so in that light, @LordVader007 (not sure why the one in the book is linear but I agree with you on the quadratic thing) -- letting $U(x)$ be the solution, we note that since $U_t(0) \equiv 0$, we have the ODE

$$U''(x) + 1 = 0 \implies U''(x) = -1$$

Integrating twice w.r.t $x$, we obtain

$$U(x) = - \frac 1 2 x^2 + c_1 x + c_2$$

for constants $c_1,c_2$. The boundary conditions become

$$U'(0) = 1 \;\;\;\;\; U(L) = 1-L$$

(continued)

Comment: So, applying the first condition:

$$U'(x) = -x + c_1 \implies U'(0) = c_1 = 1 \implies c_1 = 1$$

The second condition yields

$$U(L) = - \frac 1 2 L^2 + L + c_2 = 1-L \implies c_2 = \frac 1 2 L^2 - 2L + 1$$

Thus,

$$U(x) = - \frac 1 2 x^2 + x + \left( \frac 1 2 L^2 - 2L + 1 \right) $$

Am I getting anywhere? Sorry if this getting dumb, it's been forever since I handled any kind of differential equation to be honest. >.>

Comment: No worries, that looks fine to me now. As for why the one in the book is linear, it depends on the problem (the PDE given) and the BCs.

Comment: Hm, it looks reasonably similar to the problem I posted but I'll see if I can figure it out. Thanks for all your help, I appreciate it! ^_^

Comment: Note that this equation has a non-homogeneous term. If the equation was $u_t = u_{xx}$ then the steady-state would be linear.